# Sharepoint 2013 Custom Web Part: Get and display data from Oracle and SqlServer databases

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I'm developing a Custom WebPart to retrieve data (based on certain queries) from a SqlServer and Oracle databases:

- The data should be displayed in a grid/table/etc with sorting, filtering and pagination;
- Some queries may return a big number of rows (40000+);
- The Custom WebPart must have a "Sharepoint *look and feel*";

What is the recommended way to access and retrieve data without much performance degradation?
Using a GridView? Using Jquery Datatables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an External list and add a list view webpart. You will have the SharePoint user experience.

You can use SharePoint Designer as well as Visual Studio for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With this approach can I display data on the list based on user input? Eg.: 
- User defines on two dropdowns the min and max price and press a button "Search";
- List only shows products between min and max price.

Is this possible?