# Access external web service from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, wcf

One of my client have a SharePoint site and there they have set of sharepoint lists. A webservice they have and given access for me. What I need is to access the web service and get the data. At glance I want to access the service which is hosted in another server. What are the possible ways to do? I have tried below approaches and failed.

JSOM- Can't access cross domain

Tried call WCF from BCS- Failed ti invoke through BCS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create an external content type in order to get data from external sources. This will give you flexibility such as giving list experience(if needed), remote event receivers, integrating with SP search and etc...

You can use SharePoint Designer as well as Visual Studio for this.

This is how to do using Visual Studio:

[Create SharePoint 2013 External List using Visual Studio 2012](http://www.malindesilva.net/2014/07/sharepoint-2013-external-list.html)

[Create an External List Using C#](http://www.malindesilva.net/2014/07/create-external-list.html)

[Modifying BDC Model Entity in Business Connectivity Services](http://www.malindesilva.net/2014/08/modify-bcs-entity.html)

Here is how to do it using [SharePoint Designer](http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/02/23/walkthrough-create-a-simple-bcs-connection-with-sharepoint-designer-2010/).

You do not always need to create a list to refer the external data in lists. You can create an External Data/ Business data column and bind the content type to it when your creating the list that refers external data.

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/112523/6382). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!

Comment: @benny: Noted and modified.

Comment: +1 for honoring the rules of our community! Thanks!